# How to keep unique identity to yammer message

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, yammer

I am able to post yammer message with below snippet.

```
$http({
                        method : "POST",
                        url : "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/messages.json" ,
                        data:{
                            "body": res,
                            "group_id": 11XX
                        },
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': '*/*',
                            'Authorization': 'Bearer '+localStorage.getItem("socialToken"),
                            'accept-encoding': 'gzip',
                            'content-type': 'application/json'
                        }
                        }).then(function mySucces(response) {
                            $ionicPopup.alert({
                                title: 'Sucess',
                                template: 'Yammer Messaging Sucess'
                            });
                        }, function myError(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                            $ionicPopup.alert({
                                title: 'Messaging failed!',
                                template: 'Please login to Yammer!'
                        });
```

Now, I logged in and I posted "Anand".
Now I want to like my own message.
I do know it can be done with message ID and the same can be retrieved by GET Request.
How do I refer it actually because I have not set any reference while posting the message.I added only comments.
While posting I need to keep some reference so that it can be helpful while liking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yammer message IDs are dynamically allocated. It's not possible to provide or enforce a specific message ID.

When you post a message, it returns a JSON response containing details of the message if it was successfully created (201). It's in this format:

```
{
  "threaded_extended": {},
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": 725973788,
      "sender_id": 155231522,
      "replied_to_id": null,  
      ...
```

So I'd suggest you consume the response on SUCCESS, extract the messages.id value then perform whatever actions you'd like. You may want to use a RESTClient to get a better feel of how it works before implementing it in your code.